# Get all values in column MySQL and count PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I try to create a function that will get all values (**int**) in specific column in my database (**MySQL**), and create the total of all values. I have an error: **Resource id #12**

This is my function:

```
function vuesCours() {

    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("myDataBase", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(views) FROM articles"); 

    return $result;

}
```

And this my declaration:

```
<h4><?php echo vuesCours(); ?></h4>
```

Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: Mysql is deprecated instead use `mysqli or PDO`

Comment: Are you getting any error?? although mysql_query is deprecated, please tell error or the problem that you are facing...as Query looks fine

Comment: How are you using `$result` after returned by the `vuesCours()` function?

Comment: Check out [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) to understand how exactly you should handle the result resource. And as @Saty said please keep also in mind that `mysql` has been deprecated already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not error just you have to do one thing more after query, so try to replace following code and try again.

```
function vuesCours() {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("myDataBase", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(views) as total FROM articles"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $row['total'];
}
```

It may help you.

Comment: Thank you. I found the response at the same time of you ;)

Answer (score 1):

you need to return not results but the value of row. something like this:

```
function vuesCours() {
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("myDataBase", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(views) as total FROM articles"); 
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
    return $row['total'];
}
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
    mysql_select_db("myDataBase", $con);

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT views FROM articles"); 
$sum=0;
while($row=(mysql_fetch_row($result)))
{
     $sum=$sum+$row['views'];

}
echo $sum;
```

1) i have just changed the select query
2)we have result set of query in $result
3)mysql_fetch_row will return result row as an enumerated array
from which you can access
particular column by it's name or by giving id into subscript brackets in a line $sum=$sum+$row[index/name of column];

Comment: While this probably is a very good answer please try to provide some context. What have you changed and why?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis did you see my edited answer? and if i am wrong somewhere while explaining please correct me.